# Problem with execute procedure in PL/SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedure, ora-00900

I this is my first attempt to create procedure and execute it.
First I create simple table. DB scheme of table is here:

Table name: Ziaci

Columns:

- ZiakId - primary key, number
- Surname, varchar2
- FirstName, varchar2
- TriedaId - forgein key, number

Store procedure only insert data in table, I created store procudure with this SQL cmd:

```
create procedure ziaci_proc(surname_in in varchar2, 
firstname_in in varchar2, triedaid_in in number)
is
begin
  insert into ziaci (surname, firstname,triedaid) values (surname_in,firstname_in,triedaid_in);
  end;
```

And I try call this procudure as:

```
execute ziaci_proc('X','Y',1)
```

I get this error:

ORA-00900 invalid SQL statement

An in PL/SQL Developer IDE is with red color underlined execute word.

I test this procedure and it works good.

I can only execute this procedure with this SQL command:

```
begin
ziaci_proc('A','B',2);
end;
```

What is bad, thank for help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Calling stored procedures using `execute` as above is specific to SQL*Plus.  In fact, SQL*Plus converts `execute some_proc()` into `BEGIN some_proc(); END;`, You can see this for yourself by attempting to call a procedure that doesn't exist:

```
SQL> execute some_proc()
BEGIN some_proc(); END;

      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'SOME_PROC' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Answer (score 11):

I think you're writing command in "SQL Window". You should use "Command Window" to succesfully execute this line:

```
execute ziaci_proc('X','Y',1);
```