# Procedure execute inside SQL Developer, but not inside a script

Tags: python, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle10g

I had a procedure that was not working.
If I tried to run: "BEGIN proc_name; END;" in SQL Developer or via script I had the same error.

I've fixed the procedure and now when I run that same command in SQL Developer, it's fine, but the script returns an error.

When I try:

```
...
sql = """EXEC proc_name"""
con = connection.cursor()
con.execute( sql )
...
```

I get DatabaseError: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement, but probably is because of that: [Problem with execute procedure in PL/SQL Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203431/problem-with-execute-procedure-in-pl-sql-developer)  and I'm not really worried about it.

What is really making me curious is when I try:

```
...
sql = """BEGIN proc_name;END;"""
con = connection.cursor()
con.execute( sql )
...
```

I get the same error that I had before fix the procedure.
Do you have any idea what is going on?

PS: This is a python script using cx_Oracle and I'm using Oracle 10g.

Comment: First and second code example are the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [callproc](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/html/cursor.html#Cursor.callproc)() or [callfunc](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/html/cursor.html#Cursor.callfunc)() method on the cursor, instead of execute(). They are not exactly Py DB API compatible, but should do the job for cx_Oracle...